# vb.net add text to mysql database through php

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, httpwebrequest

I am building an app where I need to allow a user to add a large text (a story) to his account in server.

This will be done like this:

1. application developed in vb.net for article formatting
2. pass the story to php page using request variables (because direct connection to MySql server can reveal my password in app exe)
3. php file will store data to database.

But right now I get: `414 error - url too big`.

Any alternative to this ?

Comment: What's your problem with WCF?

Comment: no idea about this. worth checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try http post, modified your php.ini file to increase its max size, though if its just text I doubt you will be hitting its limit, unless the stories are really long.

Comment: yup got that working : i was actually using request variables (get) on server and post in vb.net. LOL - Kinda new to PHP. Now i made a post variable form with post in vb.net too. So everything cleared now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to SQL server, create a stored procedure and a user limited to execute that stored procedure only. Then use that user account for uploading data.

Even better would be to introduce user accounts for each user and approve credentials in that stored procedure which would avoid anonymous spamming of your database.